# Radar's radiation inside air traffic control tower

Tags: electromagnetic, radar

As a person working in a tower cab on which a ground movement radar is installed, I am curious what the typical power flux density would be inside the cab due its proximity. The frequency of the radar is about 15 Ghz, with a peak power of 10 kW.

Comment: Some insight might be gained by noting how close to your tower can "things" be detected. You might be more concerned with specular reflections from nearby "things" that peak up as they pass, rather than average direct antenna power.

Answer (score 4):

Details would be in the type or installation approval for your specific radar, but: negligible.

Point is that it's both legally necessary to not expose humans to strong electromagnetic radiation, as well as a technical necessity to focus the beam away from below.

Atop of that it's technically easy to have low side lobes in the direction perpendicular to what the radar should illuminate. And, building materials offer very high attenuation to 15 GHz.

So, you're safe. Chill.

Comment: The bean is dangerous if you are in front of it. Right under, it's much much weaker. Sane with telecom antennas,